# Does changing a Specflow scenario after it is written violate the open close principle?

Tags: c#, tdd, bdd

I am trying to learn Specflow.  I have bought a book and it arrives at the weekend.  Most of the scenarios I see online are for simple things like calculators.  For example, please see the scenario below:

```
Feature: Calculator
       In order to avoid silly mistakes
       As a math idiot
       I want to be told the sum of two numbers

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
       Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
       And I have also entered 70 into the calculator
       When I press add
       Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

which I took from here: http://specflow.org/getting-started/

This feature should never change; because the process of adding two numbers will never change i.e. 70+50 will always equal 120.  Most of the other scenarios I see e.g. logging onto a webpage should never change.

Say I have a scenario like this:

```
Feature: EligibilityCalculator
       In order to calculate offers
       As an eligibility calculator
       I want to be told a date of birth and gender
```

This feature looks ok to me.  However, what if the eligibility criteria changed in the future? For example, what if I wanted to change the criteria to say:

```
1) I want to be told a date of birth, gender and country
or
2) The Step Definitions change to only allow people over the age of 21
```

Do I just modify the feature file and step definitions or is this a poor acceptance test?

Answer (score 2):

You just modify the feature file and step definitions.

The open-closed principle means that you should avoid having to modify existing feature code in order to implement new features.

If the requirements for an existing feature change, then it is logical that the code implementing that feature (or the tests for it) needs to change. Otherwise you end up with a really large number of obsolete, useless tests and dead code.

Comment: Thanks.  So the feature in my question is of ok quality? The reason I ask is because I don't have a great deal of experience with Specflow.

Comment: @w0051977: I am not a Specflow user either, but I would expect the *As a* part to specify a user/actor external to the system, not an internal component. I would probably write the feature as "In order to receive offers, As a user, I want to be told if I am eligible based on my age and gender"